# How to access declaring type for static member in C#

Tags: c#, reflection

I have a scenario in which i need to access declaring type of an static property.the scenario is as following :

```
public static class FOO{
     public static SomeType Bar{get;set;}
}

public static class BAZ{
   public static void SomeMethod(SomeType p){
       //here i wanna get type of container of 'p' which should be FOO
   }
}    

 BAZ.SomeMethod(FOO.Bar);
```

but when i call `p.GetType().DeclaringType` i get null value, any suggestions?

Comment: *type of container of 'p'* is not unambiguous, since `SomeType` type property can be declared in more than one class. Suppose you have class `BOO` which also declares `public static SomeType Bar{get;set;}`, inside `SomeMethod` method you only have Type information of `SomeType`, how can you image finding `FOO` or `BOO` type information based on `p` ?

Comment: oh tnx for info.i have completely misunderstood scenario.what i need to do is to access container of property not the type.is it even possible?

Comment: Behnam, By *container of property* do you mean, class which declares that property ?

Comment: You can access Type information which defines property, well, with `PropertyInfo` object. Try following.  `public static void SomeMethod(PropertyInfo pInfo){
     pInfo.DeclaringType
   }`

Comment: Or else you might want to pass an expression tree, i.e. have the signature `public static void SomeMethod(Expression<Func<SomeType>> propertyExpression)`. Then you call it with `BAZ.SomeMethod(() => FOO.Bar);`. Nice calling syntax. With a bit of effort, you can finde the `PropertyInfo` from your expression tree.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `DeclaringType` only refers to nested and generic types. In this case, you have a static member of a type, not a nested type or generic type definition so it returns null as designed.  If you had a `PropertyInfo` for `Bar`, then I think you could figure out what type that property belongs to but I don't see how as a parameter (and a non-generic parameter at that), you would be able to since all you have at that point is a bare instance of the parameter type.  You've lost the context from which it came.

I would also comment that this seems like a very poor design - having to know where an instance of an object derives from introduces way too much coupling to be maintainable.

[Type.DeclaringType](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.declaringtype(v=vs.110).aspx)

[MemberInfo.DeclaringType](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.memberinfo.declaringtype(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible this way.

When you pass the SomeType parameter to SomeMethod, a reference to an object of type SomeType is passed. This object does not know anything about what other data is referencing it.